# DDD: Can I modify two aggregates in a single transaction?

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design

So I'm struggling to model a fairly simple and very common relationship.
I have a complex app with a lot of entities, I want to model a use case, and for this UC I have 3 entities, organization, user and invite. This are the business rules/constraints:

- A user can belong to one or many organizations.
- An organization can send invites to an email, the email can be an existing user or a new one. (this means creating the invite db entity)
- An organization can delete (update with status: deleted) an invite (if is not accepted yet). (this means updating the invite db entity)
- A user can accept an invite (this means updating the invite and the user)
- A user can decline an invite (this means updating the invite)

So under this context, User is an aggregate root, I think organization is another aggregate root (there are other entities that are related to the org), now I do not really understand what invite is, I'm leaning towards aggregate root as well, but the problem is that if that is the case, when accepting an invite I need to modify the invite and the user in the same transaction, which I believe is something we want to avoid.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I modify two aggregates in a single transaction?

Yes, you can... if you are willing to accept the trade offs involved (restrictions on your choice of durable storage, increased need for conflict resolution, and so on).

But: the pressure to combine aggregates into a single transaction is *often* a symptom of either (a) failing to recognize that the model should be supporting intermediate/non-equilibrium states or (b) accidental complexity in the form of incorrectly designed domain entities.

> Any ideas?

Consider whether you can satisfy your requirements by modeling the invitation process, rather than trying to model the Nouns.  Consider whether you model is best served by links to mutable data references or instead by making an immutable copy of the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for answering, wether your comment does make a lot of sense from a theoretical standpoint, I do not know how to solve this simple scenario from an implementation standpoint, I obviously do not fully understand DDD, regarding your second comment, how would that be? can you post an example of it?

Comment: In the proposed mutations, there's only one that needs to mutate two aggregates: the user accepting an invite.  For this you can have an asynchronous boundary between marking the invite as accepted and updating the user by emitting a domain event stating that "this user accepted this invite".  A background process can pick up the acceptance and then make the updates to the user.  This does introduce a [hopefully brief] period of inconsistency (from the invite's perspective, the user accepted the invite but the user aggregate doesn't yet reflect that).

Comment: An alternative approach is to explicitly model invite acceptance as a process with state: the acceptance process attempts to mark the invite as accepted; after attempting, if the invite shows as accepted, then update the user, then report success.  Once again, this will entail a period of inconsistency; the difference is that here the accept operation is considered successful after both have updated, while the background asynchronous process approach will consider the accept operation successful once the invite has been updated and the domain event emitted.

Comment: The "foreground process" approach does create some complexity in that you need some means to restart hung acceptance processes.

Comment: so I was not that far off after all, thank you very much for your clarification.

Comment: Honestly for most Intranet systems I've designed it was totally acceptable to modify more than 1 AR per transaction sometimes rather than having to deal with eventual consistency. Just make sure to keep the boundaries clean, I usually do the integration through events even if the handler is processed within the same transaction context just to reinforce the fact that it could possibility be split if needed. I'd say go for strong consistency first unless the performance/scalability cost is too high and then refactor accordingly.

Comment: For this specific process there are many ways this could be done. The organization membership could be a projection of the approved invites for instance, meaning you wouldn't even need to modify the `User` aggregate. Another approach could be as you mentioned, updating both ARs at the same time (or with a small EC delay). The problem with that is if you actually need to know the organization memberships for the invite process. For instance, do you want to prevent allowing to send invites for users already part of an organization? Does it matter if that happens?

Comment: If that matters then you may want to model the invites as part of the `User` aggregate or event create a specific `UserOrganizationMemberships` aggregate that protects the organization membership and deal with the invites processes by only tracking the active invites. e.g. `userOrganizations.inviteToOrganization(org)` and later `userOrganizations.acceptInviteToOrganization(org)`. The invites history can be tracked with persisted events for instance so there's no need to keep a collection of all past invites.

Comment: The again, perhaps the UserOrganizationMemberships boundary isin't wide enough, e.g. it wouldn't prevent inviting deactivated users because the status is out of the boundary, etc. @rage77 I'm very curious what were the comments of VoiceOfUnreason regarding immutable state modeling etc.

Comment: `"is best served by links to mutable data references or instead by making an immutable copy of the data you need."` -> Could you expand on a practical example for the above use case? Thanks